# "sample.lxc" has an unknown provider type "local" error when bootstrapping

Tags: juju

I installed Juju as documented in the website, but I get the error `"sample.lxc" has an unknown provider type "local"`.

I followed the whole process and I installed juju 1.11.0-precise-i386.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local provider has not yet landed in 1.11.x (it's in progress) . In order to use LXC as a provider you will need to use Juju .7. The way we're currently doing this is you can install `juju` along with `juju-core` and use alternatives to switch back and forth:

According to the [get started page](https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/).

> You can switch between the default (0.7) version and 1.10 versions by
>   using the following:
>
> ```
> sudo update-alternatives --set juju /usr/lib/juju-0.7/bin/juju
> ```
>
> or to the new 1.10.0 release using:
>
> ```
> sudo update-alternatives --set juju /usr/lib/juju-1.10.0/bin/juju
> ```

But to do this you need to install Juju .7 as well, which is packaged as `juju`. So you'll need to install that.

The team knows that this is a terrible user experience, but once the local provider lands in newer versions of Juju we will revise the documentation to be more sleek. The local provider should be finished in the next month or two.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i was able to switch the juju-0.7 and everything worked fine